# Custom DatabaseConnection driver does not get found by drupal!

Tags: 7, database

I need to customize a method on the DatabaseConnection_sqlsrv (MSSQL) driver, so i created a new driver class called DatabaseConnection_sqlsrvseed and extended all depended classes  from the *_sqlsrv classes.

```
class DatabaseConnection_sqlsrvseed extends DatabaseConnection_sqlsrv {
  public function driver() {
    return 'sqlsrvseed';
  }
  public function databaseType() {
    return 'sqlsrvseed';
  }
}
```

Basically all other classes in the database/sqlsrvseed folder are empty classes that inherit their functionality from their parents like this one:

```
class InsertQuery_sqlsrvseed extends InsertQuery_sqlsrv {}
```

I am doing this because i need a modification on `createFieldSql` in `DatabaseSchema_sqlsrv` to create IDENTITY fields with a Seed value.

However, whenever i set

`$database['default']['default']['driver'] = 'sqlsrvseed'`

i get the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseConnection_sqlsrvseed' not found in
>   C:[...]\includes\database\database.inc on line 1686

Although i am pretty sure that the class and all dependencies exist.
I did excactly everything like they did it in the [sqlsrv driver](http://drupal.org/node/1207972):

> Drupal and the SQL Server driver Uncompress Drupal in the web root.
>   Uncompress this driver as sites/all/modules/sqlsrv, and copy or link
>   the sqlsrv directory found inside it in includes/databases.

So I copied the files from database folder as well as the module folder. But there is a strange difference. I can't activate my custom driver module, whereas i can activate sqlsrv one. Any help? How does drupal gets to know this driver, without core modification?

Comment: Where have you put your classes? In `.inc` files properly mentioned in your `.info`?

Comment: i put them in DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/database/sqlsrvseed/. Looking at line 1686 in database.inc the require_once of the file where DatabaseConnection_sqlsrvseed is defined works. But the initialization does not...

Comment: Problem is - by doing that you hacked core. Try to wrap them into a proper module and then use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Drupal's autoload failed. For it to work you should put your classes in `.inc` file in your module, and then mention it [in `files` line of module's `.info` file](https://drupal.org/node/542202#files).

If that does not help and your classes are needed even earlier, include them in your `settings.php`:

```
require_once('path/to/module/sqlsrvseed.inc');
```

Comment: I did excactly everything like they did it in the sqlsrv driver and they follow the same approach.

https://drupal.org/node/1207972: Drupal and the SQL Server driver

Uncompress Drupal in the web root. Uncompress this driver as sites/all/modules/sqlsrv, and copy or link the sqlsrv directory found inside it in includes/databases.


So I copied the files from database folder as well as the module folder. But there is a strange difference. I can't activate my custom driver module...

Comment: Oh, if your module is not enabled, it's no surprise it fails. But I think you should edit your question telling that, and explainning **how** you can't enable it. Error message? Checkbox just grayed?.. and so on

Comment: checkbox grayed. I edited my question. But this drives me crazy... why is this that complicated and not even documented?